# Access class property from outside of class

Tags: php, oop

Suppose I had the following class:

```
class MyClass {
    public function Talk() {
        $Say = "Something";
        return $Say;
    }
}
```

I then started an instance of the class:

```
$Inst = new MyClass();
```

How can I now call $Say outside MyClass hence, for example, echo it on the document? For example, having something like:

```
$Said = "He" . $Say
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I strongly recommend you read through **http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php**.  It will teach you the fundamentals of OOP in PHP.

In your example, `$Say` is just another variable declared within `Talk()`'s scope.  It is **not** a class property.

To make it a class property:

```
class MyClass {
    public $say = 'Something';

    public function Talk() {
        return $this->say;
    }
}

$inst = new MyClass();
$said = 'He ' . $inst->say;
```

That defeats the purpose of `Talk()` however.

The last line ought to be `$said = 'He '. $inst->Talk();`

Comment: Just a point of clarification: this would make `$say` an _object_ property. A declaration like `static $say = 'Something';` would make it a _class_ property.

Answer (score 1):

`$say` is not a class property.  If it was, you would define your class like this:

```
class MyClass {
    public $say;      
}
```

It is instead a local variable of the function `Talk()`.  If you want to access it the way that you have the class defined, you would do:

```
$instance = new MyClass();
$instance->Talk();
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to make the $Say an instant variable of the MyClass class.

```
class MyClass {
    public $Say
    public function Talk() {
        $this->Say = "Something";
        return $this->Say;
    }
}
```

You could then access the instance variable from outside the class via
    $Inst->Say

Additionally it is better practice to encapsulate your class instance variables and use a "getter" method to retrieve the values.

```
class MyClass {
    private $Say
    public function Talk() {
        $this->Say = "Something";
        return $this->Say;
    }
    public getSay() {
        return $this->Say;
    }
}

$Inst = new MyClass();
echo $Inst->getSay();
```

Comment: even better is to use `__get` and `__set` to implicitly call `getSay` so that other developers are allowed the convenience of calling `$inst->Say` without worrying about calling the accessor or mutator.

Comment: I have a [chunk of code](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#97572) for dynamic accessors and mutators. It works in most cases, except where you need access by reference.

Answer (score 1):

The best practices of oop is NEVER have public properties in your class. The best way to manipulate properties of your class is to have separate methods that will return the value of the properties and set the value of the properties.
So

```
class MyClass {
    private $say;

    // common setter, invoked when we trying to set properties as they are public
    public function __set($name, $value) {
        $methodname = 'set' . ucfirst(strtolower($name));
        if (method_exists($this, $methodname)) {
            $this->$methodname($value);
        } else {
            throw new Exception ('There is no "' . $name . '" property in "' . __CLASS__ . '" class');
        }
    }

    // common getter, invoked when we trying to get properties as they are public
    public function __get($name) {
        $methodname = 'get' . ucfirst(strtolower($name));
        if (method_exists($this, $methodname)) {
            return $this->$methodname();
        } else {
            throw new Exception ('There is no "' . $name . '" property in "' . __CLASS__ . '" class');
        }
    }

    // setter for out private property $say, invoked by common setter when colling $a->say = "something";
    public function setSay($value) {
        $this->say = $value;
    }

    // getter for out private property $say, invoked by common getter when colling $a->say;
    public function getSay() {
        return $this->say;
    }

    public function Talk($monologue) {
        $this->say = (!empty($monologue))?$this->say:$monologue;
        return $this->say;
    }

}
```

So now you can access your private properties as they are public, and do all neccessary checks to not get bad values be stored in them.
Like that:

```
$a = new MyClass;
$a->say = "Hello my friends !";
$a->Talk();
$a->Talk("Good bye !");
echo $a->say;
```

Or like that:

```
$a = new MyClass;
$a->setSay("Hello my friends !");
$a->Talk();
$a->Talk("Good bye !");
echo $a->getSay();
```

For more security, you can make setSay and getSay methods private, but then the second piece of code won't work.

Comment: Why should I not have public properties in my classes?

Comment: Because if you develop big system, and some developers after you will use your classes and will be able to assign values to properties directly, that could cause unpredictable behavior of whole the system. And, when you have special methods to assign values, you can clean the data and control what value will eventually be stored in the property.

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to declare that var before your functions, eg

```
class MyClass {
  public $say;
  function Talk() {
    $this->say = "something";
  }
}
```

and then

```
$Said = "He ".$Inst->$say;
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use

```
$said = "He" . $Inst->Talk();
```

in this case, or you can
class

```
class MyClass {
var $say;
public function Talk() {
    $say = "Something";
    $this->say = $say;
    return $say;
}
}
```

and call

```
$said = "He" . $Inst->say;
```

Comment: the $Say variable is only accessible in that function - it must be converted to a property first in order to do that